# Найти последовательность букв в строке java

Tags: java

Задание: нужно проверить, содержится ли в первой строке вторая строка и вывести "Содержится" или "Не содержится". Использовать стандартные методы нельзя.

Пример:

Пользователь вводит строку (мама мыла раму) и вторую строку для проверки (му)

Вывод: Содержит

Добавлю еще кое что. Я новичок во всем) и тут первый раз и в программировании то же. Обучаюсь. Чем проще будут предложения тем лучше для меня (я хотя бы разберусь что вы предлагаете).

---

Это мой код. Он выдает ошибку. Нельзя использовать встроенные методы такие как 
`contains`, `indexOf` и другие, нужен примитивный способ через циклы.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Proba
{//проверка, содержится ли в первой строке вторая строка
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String lineOne;
        String lineTwo;
        int flag = -1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Напишите первый текст");
        lineOne = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Напишите второй текст");
        lineTwo = sc.nextLine();
        char[] lo = lineOne.toCharArray();
        char[] lt = lineTwo.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(lo.length, lt.length); i++)
        {
            if (lo[i] == lt[i])
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Приложите свой код

Comment: И заодно опишите какие способы попали под запрет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго ломал голову как можно сделать более простой код для решения данной задачи! Ответ нашелся.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test3
{//поиск подстроки в строке
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String lineOne;//первая основная строка с текстом
        String lineTwo;//поисковая строка подтекста
        boolean flag = true;//флаг выдает ответ истинно выражение или ложно
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//запускаем сканер
        System.out.println("Напишите первый текст");
        lineOne = sc.nextLine();//записываем основную строку
        System.out.println("Напишите второй текст");
        lineTwo = sc.nextLine();//записываем поисковую строку
        char[] lo = lineOne.toCharArray();//преобразовываем объект String в char (разбиваем на знаки)
        char[] lt = lineTwo.toCharArray();//преобразовываем объект String в char (разбиваем на знаки)
        for (int i = 0; i <= lo.length - lt.length; i++)//задаем размер поисковой строки
        {
            flag = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < lt.length; j++)//проверяем совпадают ли знаки первой строки со знаками из второй строки
            {
                if(lo[i + j] != lt[j])//если знаки не совпадают
                {
                    flag = false;//флаг помечаем как ложный
                    break;//прерываем проверку, переходим обратно в цикл for и проверяем следующий знак
                }
            }
            if (flag)//если нашли совпадение то флаг остается истиной
            {
                break;//прерываем процесс
            }
        }
        if (!flag)//в зависимости от состояния флага (false/true) выводим результат
        {
            System.out.println("Не содержит");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Содержит");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать. У вас цикла не верно работал. Он после проверки первых символов сразу шел в `break`. Тут только двойной цикл нужен

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proba {//проверка, содержится ли в первой строке вторая строка


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lineOne;
        String lineTwo;
        int flag = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Напишите первый текст");
        lineOne = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Напишите второй текст");
        lineTwo = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        char[] lo = lineOne.toCharArray();
        char[] lt = lineTwo.toCharArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < lo.length; i++) {
            if (lo[i] == lt[0]) {
                for (int m = i, n = 0; m < lo.length && n < lt.length; m++, n++) {
                    if (lo[m] != lt[n]) {
                        flag = 0;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag++;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == lt.length) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag > 0) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь! Все работает. Могли бы вы объяснить что это за цикл и почему в нем присутствует оператор сравнения &&? Можно ли разбить этот цикл на более простой пример?
        for (int m = i, n = 0; m < lo.length && n < lt.length; m++, n++)

Comment: @FDmitriyA `&&` - это логический оператор, а не оператор сравнения. А цикл обычный `for`. Только в нем объявлено несколько переменных и более сложное условие, чем обычно. Советую прочитать самостоятельно, т. к. не хватит символов в одном сообщении, чтобы развернуто ответить. Например [Цикл For](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vnm9T4NC2k)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "мама мыла раму";
str.contains("му")
```

**UPD:**
Раз использовать стандартные методы нельзя, то проверить можно например регуляркой:

```
Pattern.compile("му").matcher(str).find()
```

**UPD2:**
Если нужен именно цикл - то вот набросал код (не проверял):

```
String[] str = "мама мыла раму".split("");
String[] find = "му".split("");
int num = 0;
boolean isContains = false;

for ( int i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ){
    if (str[i].equals(find[num]) ) num++;
    else num = 0;
    if ( num >= find.length ){
        isContains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ( isContains ) System.out.println("Содержит");
else System.out.println("Не содержит");
```

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно условия. `Нельзя использовать встроенные методы такие как 
(contains), (indexOf) и другие нужен примитивный способ через циклы.`

Comment: @Olmicron Использовать split  и equals, то же нельзя. Нужен простейший метод перебора через fori и if для условий. Pattern то же не подходит для решения